Your Expo app is stuck on the splash screen and doesn't proceed past it
I know there are other questions like this, but none of them have answers. I followed the Expo sample exactly, but I’m encountering an issue where my project gets stuck on the splash screen in the production build. There are no errors, and all dependencies are up to date. I've tried uninstalling modules, creating a new project, but nothing seems to work. Has anyone encountered this problem or found a solution?
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'expo-router';

// Expo and native libraries
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { StatusBarStyle, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

// Context and themes
import { DataProvider } from '@/utils/DataContext';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { CustomLightTheme, CustomDarkTheme } from '@/constants/themes';
import { Colors } from '@/constants/Colors';
import { useColorScheme } from '@/hooks/useColorScheme';

// React Native libraries
//import 'react-native-reanimated';

export default function RootLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    'Ficons': require('@/assets/fonts/icomoon.ttf'),
    'Poppins-SemiBold': require('@/assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf'),
    'Poppins-Medium': require('@/assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf'),
    'Poppins-Light': require('@/assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf'),
  });

  const router = useRouter();
  const [isFirstTime, setIsFirstTime] = useState<boolean | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkFirstTime = async () => {
      try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('firstTime');
        if(value === 'false') {
          setIsFirstTime(false);
        } else {
          setIsFirstTime(true);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    };

    checkFirstTime();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();

      if (isFirstTime) {
        router.replace("/onboarding/onBoarding");
      } else {
        router.replace("/screen/Lock");
      }
    }
  }, [loaded, isFirstTime]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <DataProvider>
      <StatusBar hidden={false} backgroundColor={Colors[colorScheme ?? 'light'].StatusBar} barStyle={(Colors[colorScheme ?? 'light']?.StatusBarText ?? 'light-content') as StatusBarStyle} />
      <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? CustomDarkTheme : CustomLightTheme}>
        <Stack>
          <Stack.Screen name="onboarding" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="screen" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="+not-found" />
        </Stack>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </DataProvider>
  );
}

This is the "_layout.tsx", I tried to follow exactly the sample in expo.
